# Cannot get cached Kerberos tickets

Tags: php, iis-7.5, kerberos

I've authorized in Windows domain and want to get cache of my Kerberos ticket.
From Windows command line I can get metadata of the ticket (but not the cache itself):

```
klist tickets
```

I need the cache to use php-function `ldap_sasl_bind`, where I have to set environment variable `KRB5CCNAME` with the path to cache ticket.
Is there a way to get Kerberos ticket cache in Windows (or path to the cache)?
Environment: Windows 2008, IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 1):

Sas,

Check out the following article by Tim Springston of Microsoft--

### Viewing and Purging Cached Kerberos Tickets

@ https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tspring/2014/06/23/viewing-and-purging-cached-kerberos-tickets/

In it, he provides two PowerShell scripts which, upon running--

> ... a quick and easy way to list the cached tickets for all users on a computer. We are also left with a quick way to purge all cached tickets from a server while keeping the server available to provide services.

Hope this post at least helps you, at a very minimum.

Best,
-Rush